# How do you delete attachments from Trello cards using cURL?

Tags: api, curl, trello

I am trying to delete attachments from Trello cards using cURL.

I tried setting the attachments field in the card to 0 (it is currently 1 since there is an attachment). I think it is not working because attachments are under badges in the JSON hierarchy.

I tried all of these (with key/token params):

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/:cardId?attachments=0"
curl -X PUT "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/:cardId?badge.attachments=0"
curl -X PUT "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/:cardId?badge:attachments=0"
```

None seem to work.  Maybe this isn't even the right way to delete a Trello attachment using cURL??

I would expect the attachments number in the JSON output to go to 0 (and hopefully thereby disconnect the attachment from the card) but it won't change. I can successfully close the card by swapping in `closed=true` for the `attachments=0` but maybe this is the wrong approach altogether but the API documentation for Trello is sparse on deleting attachments.

Comment: Does `curl -X DELETE https://api.trello.com/1/cards/:cardId/attachments/:attachmentId` do what you want?

Comment: Worked like a charm! curl -X DELETE "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/*CardId*/attachments/*attachmentId*?key=*key*&token=*token*"  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Trello's REST API properly supports use of HTTP verbs for deleting resources, so [the documentation for deleting an attachment](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsidattachmentsidattachment-1) is separate from the documentation for updating a card or attachment.

You can use the following:

```
curl -X DELETE https://api.trello.com/1/cards/:cardId/attachments/:attachmentId
```